# Excel VBA Match function returns Error 2042

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Error 2042 in the Match function for the variable findDeptrow in my VBA subroutine.
Tried changing around data types with no luck.

Thanks for answers!

Here is the code:

```
Sub calculatechange()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim findDeptrow As Variant
Dim findTypecol As Variant

Set ws1 = Workbooks("woorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("works2")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("works2")

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("D3:H11").ClearContents

For i = 2 To lastrow
findDeptrow = Application.Match(ws2(i, 5), ws1.Columns(2), 0)
findTypecol = Application.Match(ws2.Cells(i, 13), ws1.Rows(2), 0)
ws1.Cells(CInt(findDeptrow), CInt(findTypecol)) = ws1.Cells(CInt(findDeptrow), CInt(findTypecol)) + ws2.Cells(i, 14)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That means that the value wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will fix the problem:

```
findDeptrow = Application.Match(ws2.Cells(i, 5).Value, ws1.Columns(2), 0)
findTypecol = Application.Match(ws2.Cells(i, 13).Value, ws1.Rows(2), 0)
```

You need to pass a value as first argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match

Comment: `.Value` is implicit. Adding it is good for explicitness, but won't change the result.

Comment: In my experience adding .Value often solves problems. I tried the provided code on my machine and it worked. Of course, without sample data it is hard to tell if this solves the problem in every case.